# NIFI - Jolt Specification - Concatenate

Tags: json, concatenation, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to concatenate two strings. Since the string name contains `.`, that particular field is not read in the concat expression.

json input:

```json
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "test.flu": "flu1",
      "reportId": 11
    },
    {
      "test.flu": "flu2",
      "reportId": 12
    }
  ],
  "type": "node",
  "labels": "label1"
}
```

jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          "id": "=concat(@(1,test.flu),' ',@(1,reportId))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

output:

```json
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "test.flu": "flu1",
      "reportId": 11,
      "id": " 11" // expected output: "flu1 11"
    },
    {
      "test.flu": "flu2",
      "reportId": 12,
      "id": " 12"
    }
  ],
  "type": "node",
  "labels": "label1"
}
```

Since my concatenate string has a period, it is not reading that string. I am sure this will be very minor fix. Looking forward for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `.` character to change its meaning:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          "id": "=concat(@(1,test\\.flu),' ',@(1,reportId))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```